# Jira Soap with a Php

Tags: php, jsp, soap, jira, jira-plugin

I have seen little to know instruction on using php to develop a client website to make remote calls to JiRA.

Currently I'm trying to make a soap client using JSP/Java to connect to a local jira instance. I would like to create and search issues that is all. We are currently having some problems using Maven2 and getting all the files we need from the repository since we are behind a major firewall(yes I've used the proxy).

I have a lot of experience with PHP and would like to know if using the PHP soapclient calls can get the job done.

http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php

Comment: Its Jira 4.4.3 that we are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it can be done, using [SOAP](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/Creating+a+JIRA+SOAP+Client) or [XML-RPC](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/JIRA+XML-RPC+Overview).

Using the APIs is pretty much straight forward - have a look at [the API documentation](http://docs.atlassian.com/rpc-jira-plugin/4.4/com/atlassian/jira/rpc/soap/JiraSoapService.html) to find the right functions for you. your code should look something like :

```
<?
$soapClient = new SoapClient("https://your.jira/rpc/soap/jirasoapservice-v2?wsdl");
$token = $soapClient->login('user', 'password');
...  
... # get/create/modify issues
... 
?>
```

Example of adding a new comment:

```
$issueKey = "key-123";
$myComment = "your comment";

$soapClient = new SoapClient("https://your.jira/rpc/soap/jirasoapservice-v2?wsdl");
$token = $soapClient->login('user', 'password');
$soapClient->addComment($token, $issueKey, array('body' => $myComment));
```

Example of creating an issue:

```
$issue = array(
    'type'=>'1',
    'project'=>'TEST',
    'description'=>'my description',
    'summary'=>'my summary',
    'priority'=>'1',
    'assignee'=>'user',
    'reporter'=>'user',
);
$soapClient = new SoapClient("https://your.jira/rpc/soap/jirasoapservice-v2?wsdl");
$token = $soapClient->login('user', 'password');
$soapClient->createIssue($token, $issue);
```

Note that you need to install `php-soap` in linux (or it's equivalent in windows) to be able to use the SOAP library.